# SQL Server - How is a row updated under the hood?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

When SQL Server updates a row in a table, is the update always done 'in place', or is the row deleted first and then re-inserted? If the update is done 'in place', is this always the case, or are there situations where a delete is done first and then an update?

We have a developer on the team that is saying that when a table has a unique constraint on it, and it's included in replication (transactional replication), a delete is always done first and then an insert. I wanted to verify if this is ever the case.

SQL Server 2008 R2

Comment: Updates can be accomplished either through an in-place modification of data, or through a delete/insert.  Having said that, why do you care?  The operation either succeeds or fails in both cases.

Comment: When If it's done via a delete/insert, would a trigger fire that was set to execute on deletes?

Comment: No. It's logically still an update regardless of whether physically or not it is implemented as a delete insert pair. In reality even a single update statement can get a mix of actions as shown here http://stackoverflow.com/a/14082375/73226 (where the 9 update operations get converted to 1 delete, 8 updates, and an insert.)

Comment: @MartinSmith I think that qualifies as an answer, on its own merit.

Comment: @Randolph I didn't submit an answer as I don't know whether or not transactional replication would in any way affect anything and don't currently have time or inclination to research that.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not a replication guru, but record may be marked as deleted only in case when an update is generating Page Split.

For the case of replication you can test it by looking at DBCC PAGE and look through transaction log.